# Codeigniter with subfolders and uri segments

Tags: codeigniter, uri, segments

I have a site called: orders.

In the controllers folder I have a sub folder called: manage.

In there I have a controller called: editOrder

In the editOrder controller I have an index function that get an $id as a parameter.

In one of my forms I have a link to: editOrder/1

In my route file I have this code: `$route['editOrder'] = 'manage/editOrder';`
The link gives the error page not found.

I tried to go to the page manually, like this: `http://localhost/orders/editOrder/1`
Page not found

I tried this way:

In my route file:

```
$route['editOrder/(:num)'] = "manage/editOrder/$1";
```

Page not found

I have changed my config file to:

```
$config['uri_protocol'] = 'PATH_INFO';
```

$config['enable_query_strings'] = TRUE;

And tried this way:

```
http://localhost/orders/?c=editOrder&m=index&id=1
```

That takes me to the home page.

How can I pass the id segment to the editOrder controller?????

Ahhhhhhhhhh

How would I call this controller????

Comment: could you tell in detail what url do you have and how it should be changed/routed?

Comment: Do any of your SEF urls work? If not, it could be your htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure:

1. Your custom route comes after the 2 default ones. So it should be:

   ```
   $route['default_controller'] = "defaultController";
   $route['404_override'] = '';
   $route['editOrder/(:num)'] = "manage/editOrder/index/$1";
   ```
2. Your controller file `editOrder.php` has a `class editOrder extends CI_Controller` and is inside the folder `"controllers/manage/"`;
3. Your editOrder controller has a `function index($id) {}` method;

To sum up, if you're going to call a method, you need to specify it. In case of routing, that means you have to specify even the index() method.